# Sort list of lists first by year, then by month

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of lists that looks something like this:

```
dateList = [['2014', '4'], ['2015', '6'], ['2017', '6'], ['2016', '2'], ['2016', '3'], ['2017', '9'], ['2016', '6'], ['2017', '3'], ['2014', '8'], ['2014', '10'], ['2017', '10'], ['2014', '9'], ['2014', '3'], ['2015', '11'], ['2015', '2']]
```

I have been trying to sort it by year first, and then by month. I've been successful in sorting it by year using

```
sortedList = sorted(dateList, key = lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

However, I can't figure out a way to sort it by month afterwards while keeping the years in ascending order.

Comment: Try passing a tuple

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Without the `int`, 10 would come before 9 for the months.

Comment: @fuglede good point, but then *only* the months need to be converted, the OP's current code doesn't gain any benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a tuple:

```
sorted(dateList, key = lambda x: (int(x[0]),int(x[1])))
```

But this looks better:

```
sorted(dateList, key = lambda x: tuple(map(int,x)))
```

And another alternative could be to use:

```
import datetime 
sorted(dateList, key = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join(x),'%Y%m'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first one as it is more in line with my code and seems to be more pythonic.

Comment: You're welcome. The 2nd one is more pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're in need of a natural sorting of your data. You can use the [`natsort`](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) package to do this, without having to pass a key at all -

```
import natsort

natsort.natsorted(dateList)

[['2014', '3'],
 ['2014', '4'],
 ['2014', '8'],
 ['2014', '9'],
 ['2014', '10'],
 ['2015', '2'],
 ['2015', '6'],
 ['2015', '11'],
 ['2016', '2'],
 ['2016', '3'],
 ['2016', '6'],
 ['2017', '3'],
 ['2017', '6'],
 ['2017', '9'],
 ['2017', '10']]
```